# Disadvantages of Using ThreadPool

Tags: threadpool

Can Anybody please elaborate the `Disadvantages` of using `ThreadPools`.

One `disadvantage` that I found is **task starvation**.

```
Please add if you think there are more disadvantages
```

Comment: The problem of task starvation is not limited to the use of a thread pool. It's a potential problem in any multithreading scenario or multitasking operating system.

Comment: Is there a particular question about ThreadPools you were wondering about?  This one is rather broad.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the state and priority of the thread in thread pool 
Can't give a stable identity and keep track on it 
If you need a single thread to do a single task thread pool is not needed